# Filter on date in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert a date time column to date and get all the rows in a particular day . But when try it. The query returns 0 rows .What is wrong with this code 
        where date(`a`.`refresh_time`) = '2016-06-11'

Comment: It would help if you showed data, and the actual query (or a reasonable facsimile of both).

Comment: doesn't look too terrible. His code has back-ticks in it, thus making the formatting of the question go sour. Maybe you lack that data, or you are British looking for November 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not!!! use a function on a field in WHERE clause like the Answer from @scaisEdge. If you do that like this sample MySQL must read ALL rows in the table convert it with your function and can then compare it. And it never can use a index

If is better and quicker to use like this

**SAMPLE**

```
WHERE `a`.`refresh_time` >=  '2016-06-11 00:00:00' AND `a`.`refresh_time` <=  '2016-06-11 23:59:59';
```

**OR**

```
WHERE `a`.`refresh_time` BETWEEN  '2016-06-11 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-11 23:59:59';
```

So MySQL can direct use a INDEX to find the correct ROWs

You can test it with EXPLAIN before your SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct date_format

```
 where date_format(`a`.`refresh_time`'%Y-%m-%d') = '2016-06-11'
```

Comment: of what you thanking   me  .. if you think my anser is useful  you can rate it ..